# Inserting multiple entities into many-to-many linking table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

My web application has a many-to-many link between the `Station` and `Timetable` entities, and the entity that links them is called `StationTimetable`, which also holds data about the linkage between the two entities. When I create a new `Timetable`, I want to create new (and multiple) `StationTimetable` entries in the database to correspond to this new `Timetable`.

So far I've managed to get the application to save just one `StationTimetable` entry when the user creates a new timetable. I sort of understand why this is, and I've attempted to modify it to save multiple entries however I'm now hitting a brick wall in my knowledge.

So, I have a `TimetablesCreateViewModel` which is the model my view uses:

```
public class TimetablesCreateViewModel
{
    public Timetable Timetable { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<StationTimetable> StationTimetables { get; set; }

    public Station Station { get; set; }

    public SelectList StationList { get; set; }
}
```

In my view, I'm letting the user insert up to 10 `StationTimetable` entries:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StationTimetables.StationId, Model.StationList, "---", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control col-md-2" })</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StationTimetables.Arrival, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.StationTimetables.Departure, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
    </tr>
}
```

And then, in my controller method, I want to do something like the following:

```
public ActionResult Create(TimetablesCreateViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Timetables.Add(viewModel.Timetable);

        // Somehow loop over viewModel.StationTimetables and add them here?
        // db.StationTimetables.Add(viewModel.StationTimetable);

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

The immediate problem seems to be that the `DropDownListFor` and `EditorFor` methods in my view are complaining, and that makes sense as I've specified `StationTimetables` in my view model to be `IEnumerable`, and I can't access the `StationId`, `Arrival` and `Departure` properties of `IEnumerable`. Those properties are part of the entity that `IEnumerable` holds.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to use the `Html` helper to create a form where I can populate `StationTimetables` with a number of `StationTimetable` entities. If I could just get multiple `StationTimetable` entries to my `Create` method, I don't think I'll have a problem adding them to the database after that.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Is there other navigation properties in the `Timetable` and `Station` classes? And about complaining Html helpers, maybe I'd use `StationTimetables.ToList()` before accessing properties.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your `StationTimetables` property `IList` and use the indexer so that the properties are correctly named and can be bound on post back

```
@for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  <tr>
    <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StationTimetables[i].StationId, Model.StationList, "---", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control col-md-2" })</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.StationTimetables[i].Arrival, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.StationTimetables[i].Departure, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
  </tr>
}
```

This will generate the correct name attributes for example

```
<input name="StationTimetables[0].StationId" ...>
<input name="StationTimetables[1].StationId" ...>
```

If you cant change it from `IEnumerable`, you can create a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `StationTimetable`

Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/StationTimetable.cshtml

```
@model YourAssembly.StationTimetable
<tr>
  <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StationId, (SelectList)ViewData["StationList"], "---", new { @class = "form-control col-md-2" })</td>
  <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Arrival, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
  <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Departure, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
</tr>
```

and then in the main view

```
@EditorFor(m => m.StationTimetables, new { StationList = Model.Model.StationList })
```

This approach means you need to initialize the `StationTimetables` property with 10 items in the controller before you pass the model to the view.

In any case, I recommend the `EditorFor()` approach in your case because of a bug (reported but not yet solved) in using `DropDownListFor()` in a `for` loop.

However I suspect you don't really always have exactly 10 station timetables (*I'm letting the user insert **up** to 10*) which makes this approach inflexible - for example if you add validation attributes to the properties, the model will be invalid unless all 10 time table properties are filled in. It would be better to use javascript or the [BeginCollectionItem](https://github.com/danludwig/BeginCollectionItem) helper to dynamically add a new timetable. A example of both approaches is included in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308)